# Import Instagram photos as WordPress posts

Tags: php, wordpress, instagram

I'm using this plugin, laid out here: http://mlitzinger.com/articles/instagram-to-wordpress-posts/

I've installed the Crontrol plugin, but I've only managed to get one post to import one time. The Instagram data is being returned properly, so I'm assuming it has something to do with the post insertion. This is the data used to insert the fetched Instagram posts:

```
$json_feed = file_get_contents($url, false, $args);
$json_feed = json_decode($json_feed);

foreach($json_feed->data as $post):
    if(!slug_exists($post->id)):
        $new_post = wp_insert_post(array(
            'post_content'  => '<a href="'. esc_url( $post->link ) .'" target="_blank"><img src="'. esc_url( $post->images->standard_resolution->url ) .'" alt="'. $post->caption->text .'" /></a>',
            'post_date'     => date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $post->created_time),
            'post_date_gmt' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $post->created_time),
            'post_status'   => 'publish',
            'post_title'    => $post->id,
            'post_name'     => $post->id,
            'post_category' => array(7)
        ), true);
    endif;
endforeach;

function slug_exists($post_name){
    global $wpdb;
    if($wpdb->get_row("SELECT post_name FROM wp_posts WHERE post_name = '" . $post_name . "'", 'ARRAY_A')):
        return true;
    else:
        return false;
    endif;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of trying to create my own plugin that would have to be maintained each time Instagram updates, I decided to just go with https://ifttt.com/ since it includes both Wordpress and Instagram. It listens for an Instagram post and then inserts a post in Wordpress with the formatting I define.